# Does a crystalline ferromagnetic solid break the rotational symmetry twice?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, crystals, ferromagnetism

Both Heisenberg ferromagnets and crystalline solids break the rotational symmetry in space. Now consider a crystalline ferromagnetic solid. By virtue of being in a crystalline phase, it already broke the rotational symmetry. Having broken that, how can it further break the rotational symmetry which is already broken (by achieving a ferromagnetic order)? Also, why should that have additional consequences?

Comment: Notice that crystals break also and foremost _translational_ symmetry. Also, ferromagnets do not always break rotational symmetry. Sometimes they break discrete symmetries between up/down, for example.

Comment: @fra_pero Thanks, it was really vague. I have reformulated the question.

Comment: You may want to differentiate between spin rotational/translational symmetry and atomic position symmetries. They are not the same thing since you can have one without the other.

Comment: @KFGauss Can you write it as an answer? I think that is the correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing spatial rotation symmetry and spin rotation symmetry. They are different symmetries (and both are present in nature).

In terms of group theory we will say that spin rotation symmetry is manifested by invariance of the hamiltonian with respect to group $SU(N)_{\text{spin}}$ where $N=2S+1$. Spatial symmetry by $SO(3)_{\text{space}}$. If you have both independently then the hamiltonian is invariant with respect to $SU(N)_{\text{spin}} \times SO(3)_{\text{space}}$, any combination of the two. You can also have the hamiltonian be invariant to $SO(3)_{\text{spin,space}}$. This is a subgroup of $SU(N)_{\text{spin}} \times SO(3)_{\text{space}}$, in which rotations are taken simultaneously in space and spin space. Now most systems are symmetric with respect to $SU(N)_{\text{spin}} \times SO(3)_{\text{space}}$, however the action of physically doing a rotation corresponds to $SO(3)_{\text{spin,space}}$. This is one reason to be confused. Pure spin rotation ($SU(N)_{\text{spin}}$) can be obtained with magnetic fields.

Now we will say that a system breaks a symmetry spontaneously if the observed ground state is not symmetric with respect to a given group although the hamiltonian is. Ferromagnetic systems spontaneously break $SU(N)_{\text{spin}}$ symmetry and crystals $SO(3)_{\text{space}}$ symmetry. So, to answer your question, **they do not break the same symmetry**. A ferromagnetic crystal will break both.

They also break $SO(3)_{\text{spin,space}}$ although it is not necessarily the case that when the first two are broken, this last will be broken. You could imagine a system in which the spin rotation symmetry breaking perfectly compensates the spatial rotation symmetry breaking.

Comment: Nice answer, even though the question is so basic that I don't think it is needed to go into these details of group theory. Also, you are implicitly treating the spin in quantum mechanics, which of course is correct; however the question and my reply make perfectly sense also in classical terms.

Comment: _Most importantly_, in quantum mechanics the spin symmetry group is actually $SU(N)$ where $N = 2S+1$ are the possible spin orientations. In general $S$ can be different than $1/2$.

Comment: Finally, I also do not agree with `they do not break the same symmetry`. Again, you can discuss this in classical terms. Take a square lattice, if spin is not orientated, there is symmetry under $\pi/2$ rotation around each site. Now orient the spin on the plane. The $\pi/2$ symmetry is gone. This is _exactly_ the same symmetry you'd break with, say, a lattice distortion (or considering another lattice, e.g. rectangular).

Comment: You are right about $SU(N)$, will correct! However I don't agree with your last comment. You need to consider spin rotation symmetry as different symmetry than spatial rotation symmetry. You can probe for spin rotation symmetry breaking with magnetic field effects which you will not be able to do with a purely spatial symmetry breaking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. A symmetry is either broken or unbroken. Breaking the symmetry twice does not make any sense.

The ferromagnetic phase would in general break *additional* rotational symmetry.

In other words, while it is true that the crystal breaks the rotational symmetry for *all* rotation angles around *any* axis, it preserves in general rotational symmetry for discrete angles around some axes. Then the ferromagnetic phase would break one or more of the *remaining* crystal symmetries.

For example, a cubic crystal is still symmetric for rotations of $\pi/2$ around the cubic axes. If now you have a ferromagnetic phase with spins polarized along the $z$ axis, you see that rotational symmetries around the $x$ and $y$ axes have been broken.